# Jquery Waypoints .sticky Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-waypoints

So I've done everything that is supposed to happen in order to initialize the jquery waypoints-sticky plugin, but it isn't working: included jquery, waypoints, and waypoints-sticky, and called the function:
[image]
[image]

```
$('.my-element').waypoint('sticky');
```

However, the console reads ("The sticky method does not exist in jQuery Waypoints."):

[image]

What could I possibly be missing? Nothing online gives me any ideas at all. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Are you sure that your code snippet is being run after the waypoints-sticky file is loaded?

Comment: Hi @JeffKoch well the code I am using is included after the waypoints-sticky.js. Updated the screenshot above to illustrate. Anything I could be missing? Could the browser not have fully read the waypoints file causing the other to load before?

Comment: It's entirely possible -- see answer below

Answer (score 1):

This shortcut requires the jQuery build of Waypoints.

First, include the shortcut script after the main Waypoints script.

```
<script src="/path/to/lib/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/shortcuts/sticky.min.js"></script>

var sticky = new Waypoint.Sticky({
  element: $('.basic-sticky-example')[0]
})
```

Have you seen http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that everything's getting loaded before your code executes.  Try wrapping your code in a $(document).ready() call, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.my-element').waypoint('sticky');
});
```

Equivalently, and slightly more concise:

```
$(function () {
    $('.my-element').waypoint('sticky');
});
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. But unfortunately this still will not work for me. Should I put a delay on the loading of the waypoint function?

Comment: The thing is that I am using prototyping software and putting javascript into it.. Everything is loading that's why its weird that it won't work. I have used other js plugins with no problem (skrollr, etc).

Comment: But the worst part is the regular waypoints works. Is there a way to use the regular waypoints to perform a sticky function?